# What is the best pattern to set initial focus on a field in an LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a form in an LWC containing a number of `lightning-input` components and I want the focus to be on the first field when the component initially displays. This works:

```
async connectedCallback() {

    ...

    // Focus on first input field (once rendering done)
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        const firstInput = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input');
        if (firstInput) firstInput.focus();
    }, 0);
}
```

but is there a better pattern than using the timeout? (Without the timeout focus is not set.)

The subject is not mentioned in the [Lifecycle Hooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_lifecycle_hooks) documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you can use `renderedCallback()` to set the focus (which will also cause the focus to shift every time you trigger a render), but doing it the way you are is also perfectly acceptable. The reason why you have to "wait" (via `setTimeout`) in `connectedCallback()` is because the component is not actually "fully rendered" at this point in time. See the [Lifecycle Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks) chart to understand why. The children are rendered after `connectedCallback()`, and `connectedCallback()` is called before `render()` has even been called on the parent.

Comment: Thanks; that flow chart is clearer on the ordering. Perhaps needing an `initialRender` guard in `renderedCallback` (in the page I linked to) makes that approach less attractive.

Comment: @KeithC Precisely why I'd use setTimeout for that purpose. Less boilerplate to make it reasonable.